# Caliburn IoC is not initialized

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I'm creating a Windows Phone 8.1 app and one of the features is voice commands. The flow is like this:

1. I press the search button and say a command "MyAppName do something"
2. In the App.xaml.cs I have the `OnActivated` function, where I check to see which page from my app can handle the command, and I navigate to that page

If the app is opened when I give the command, or even if it's in the background, then everything is ok. However, if the app is completely closed, when it is activated by the voice command, I get an exception saying that IoC is not initialized. In the OnActivated function I'm trying to navigate using something like this:

```
//IPageNavigationService is a wrapper for INavigationService from Caliburn
var navigationService = IoC.Get<IPageNavigationService>();
```

I also try to navigate using:

```
RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyView), args);
```

but RootFrame is null.

Is there a way I can manually initialize the IoC for Caliburn? I noticed that it doesn't get initialized if the app is started by voice commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
  if ( args.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand )
  {
                Initialize();
                PrepareApplication();
                PrepareViewFirst();
                var service = IoC.Get<IService>();
                DisplayRootView(typeof(MyView));
  }
}
```

I fixed the issue by manually initializing Caliburn.Micro. You can read more details [here](http://thewindev.net/daily-tip-1-ioc-is-not-initialized/)

Answer (score 0):

Since the non-Silverlight application is more like the WinRT is usually configured accordingly for the INavigationService;

```
private static INavigationService _navservice; // declared at top of class

protected override void Configure(){
   //viewmodel inclusions into container here...

  PrepareViewFirst();
}

protected override void PrepareViewFirst(Frame rootFrame)
{
    _navservice = container.RegisterNavigationService(rootFrame);
}
```